Hide date beneath Lightningchart ChartXY with tickstrategy AxisXStrategies.DateTime and dateOrigin set
I'm using Lightningchart (v5+) to display a real-time XY chart of an EEG signal. Everything works exactly like I expected, but I can't find a way to hide the date displayed beneath the chart.
const dateOrigin = new Date();
chart.getDefaultAxisX().setTickStrategy(AxisTickStrategies.DateTime, (tickStrategy) => {
    return  tickStrategy
    .setDateOrigin(dateOrigin)
    .setFormattingSecond(
      undefined,
      { hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric', second: 'numeric', hour12: false },
      (x) => 'minor'
   )
} )  

The data displayed looks something like:
x: 1714734098, // Epoch Timestamp,
y: 0.5 //voltage

I tried using AxisTickStrategies.Time. That one hides the label beneath, but that strategy does not provide the extensive formatting options  AxisTickStrategies.DateTime gives me. The X value displays an unformatted Unix timestamp using this strategy, which I don't want.
I have to set some sort of origin to be able to draw properly.
Is there some kind of method / flag or styling option available to hide the date beneath the chart? I can't find anything in the docs.
I'm not allowed to place images here yet (first post) but it's the date that's displayed right under the chart in a seperate label.

https://lightningchart.com/js-charts/docs/features/axis/#hide-great-ticks
axis.setTickStrategy(AxisTickStrategies.DateTime, ticks => ticks
    .setGreatTickStyle(emptyTick)
)

Listed under Features > Axis > Date-Time Axis

Thank you!! That was an easy fix. I did not recognize that label being a 'Tick' or a 'GreatTick' in this case so I overlooked this option.

Whats GreatTick? what does this mean?
